# How to get Apple dictation to work with YouTube?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, youtube, voice-dictation, voice

I seem to be having problems using Apple dictation to dictate comments associated with a YouTube video. Is anyone having this problem, and what do I need to do to make Apple dictation work with it?

Comment: What kinds of problems do you have? Can you clarify what happens when you try to dictate a comment? What browser version are you using? Which macos version are you using?

Comment: I am using Google Version 92.0.4515.107 (Official Build) (x86_64). I am able to dictate now in Stack Exchange, as I am dictating my responses to your questions now. I am using the Accessibility>Voice Control, Enable Voice Control service to do this. However this service does not work in Youtube.com commenting field.. when I am in "Dictation Mode" it will not enter text into the  Youtube comments field... but I am able to use the Keyboard>Dictation service instead....